# How to record a video in headless mode for test cases using karate

Tags: karate

I'm automating my test cases using the Karate for UI automation.
I'm using headless mode in google chrome for running the test cases.
Is there a way to record a video of the execution of the test cases?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so - but you are welcome to do some research and contribute code to Karate if needed.